# MFC CtabControl CTreeViewControl

Tags: mfc

Good afternoon

I use a tabControl and a treeViewControl. I use "OnSelchangingTabcontrol(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)" and in certain condition I want to prohibit the change of the selected item. How do I cancel the event?
I have the same problem for the treeViewControl.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `OnSelchangingTabcontrol()` body after you check for the conditions do this:

```
if(/*erroneous condition*/)
{
  *pResult = 1;
  return;
}
```

The same thing applies to tree view event. Make sure you handle `XX_CHANGING` event, not `XX_CHANGED`